# Content Type Created By, Created On, Last Modified

Tags: content-type, sharepoint-foundation

I'm looking to determine who created a content type and when. The standard page for a content type does not provide this information.

Can someone direct me to where I can find this information in SharePoint Foundation 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, i dont think there's a property which specifies this information. Using SharePoint Manager (http://spm.codeplex.com/) it doesn't display this info.

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the **audit logging** feature within SharePoint.

- [How to enable Audit functionality in SharePoint 2010](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/Pages/How-to-enable-Audit-functionality-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx)
- [SharePoint 2010 Foundation Audit Settings](http://wyldesharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/06/sharepoint-2010-foundation-audit.html)

PS. I'm not sure, you can reveal the content type creator in the audit logs :)

Comment: If you enable auditing now you won't magically get historical data.

Comment: True, but if he would like to audit things in the future - he's now aware of the audit functionality :)